# Necessary and sufficient condition for the probability current being zero in quantum theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, probability

I am self-studying introductory quantum theory and I am stuck on a question from an undergraduate
course regarding the continuity equation / probability current.

> For $\Psi(x,t)$ as a solution of Schrodinger's Equation in one dimension, with real potential $V(x)$, show that the probability current is identically zero if and only if there is a nowhere-zero function $\lambda(t)$ such that $\lambda(t)\Psi(x,t)$ is real-valued.

In one dimension the probability current is
$$\large j(x,t)=\frac{i\hbar}{2m}(\Psi\bar\Psi_x-\Psi_x\bar\Psi)$$
for wave function $\Psi$, where $\bar\bullet$ denotes complex conjugate, and defining $\rho=\lvert\Psi\rvert^2$, the continuity equation holds as
$$\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial j}{\partial x}=0. $$

I can see that
$$j\equiv0
\iff\Psi\bar\Psi_x\equiv\Psi_x\bar\Psi
\iff\Psi\bar\Psi_x\text{ real valued $\forall x,t$}
\iff \frac{\Psi_x}{\Psi}\text{ real valued $\forall x,t$}.$$
and that we have that $\rho=\lvert\Psi\rvert^2$ must be a function of $x$ only.

But here I am stuck. What am I missing?

Comment: Considered $\bar \lambda \lambda (\Psi_x\bar\Psi - \bar \Psi_x \Psi)=0$?

Comment: @CosmasZachos The reverse implication is clear but I'm unsure how to go about the forward direction

Comment: If, for all $\lambda(t)\Psi(x,t)$, st. ..., were not real valued, the above quantity would fail to vanish.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Following from that, $$\bar\lambda \lambda(\Psi_x\bar\Psi-\bar\Psi_x \Psi)=0\iff\overline{\lambda\Psi_x}\lambda\Psi\text{ is real}$$  We can find a point where $\lambda\Psi$ is not real but how do we know the product with $\overline{\lambda\Psi_x}$ is not real at this point?

Comment: See the answer!  $\lambda\Psi$ is then 0 or its phase is stable under *x* variation, so *some λ*  makes it real!

Answer (score 0):

*t* is irrelevant here, a constant, so we drop it from the discussion. Consider the polar representation
$$
\Psi(x)=r(x)e^{i\theta (x)},
$$
for real *r* and *θ*.

Thus,
$$\Psi\bar\Psi_x-\Psi_x\bar\Psi= -2ir^2 \theta_x.$$

So, for zero current, *θ* is a  constant function, except at the zeros of *r*. Take the phase of *λ* to cancel the phase of *θ* when it's constant, so $\lambda \Psi$ is real; or 0, which is real.

You saw in your comments how the reverse holds:
$$\bar \lambda \lambda (\Psi\bar\Psi_x-\Psi_x\bar\Psi)=0 ~~\implies ~~ \Psi\bar\Psi_x-\Psi_x\bar\Psi= 0.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In the notes there has been no mention so far of polar representations so I'm led to believe that it is not necessary. Why do you claim $t$ is irrelevant? I believe the question is worded so that the form of $\Psi$ remains general

Comment: You may keep writing it, but there are no derivatives w.r.t. *t*, so it is part of the definition of the symbols. The entire discussion holds for any *t*.   So it decouples from any and all considerations displayed here. One does not *need* the polar representation, but it renders all algebra and arguments virtually trivial.

Comment: Ok cool that’s useful. Since we are working in one dimension, I’m wondering what $r$ and $\theta$ represent in this context. Is it standard plan polar coordinates with $y$ set to zero, so for example $\theta$ can either be $0$ or $\pi$?

Comment: Nothing to do with x, or space. It is the representation of an arbitrary complex number as a radius and a phase on the complex plane!